# CSS Help - Footer for Mobile Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am currently working on a mobile website and I could use some help with its footer.

Here is an image of how its supposed to look:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/alH8M.jpg

It should have the following:

1) the width needs to work on different mobile devices so it cant be fixed

2) the margin to the left of home and to the right of newsletter should be equal

3) if the devices width isnt big enough for the footer to be displayed in one line, the links should be displayed in multiple "lines". What im trying to say is, there should be no horizontal scrolling

Ive been fiddling around for ages now and cant get it to work. Heres some basic code to get started:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Unternehmen</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kompetenz</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Produkte</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Partner</a></li>
        <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me!

Comment: can you specify the css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nav { background: #016d9b; }
nav ul { text-align: center; padding: 0; }
nav ul li { display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid white; padding: 0 10px; margin: 10px 0; }
nav ul li:last-child { border-right: none }
nav ul li a { color: white; text-decoration: none; }
```

`ul` with text alignment to the center and `li` displayed as inline block.

I think this should handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav{width:100%; display:block;}
nav ul{padding:0px; margin:0px;}
nav ul li{ width:20%; float:left;}
```

Comment: should do a js fiddle for him/her

Comment: this doesnt work at all. Neither is the margin to the left equal to the margin on the right nor does it work when the browser is very narrow

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
nav ul { list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
nav ul li { float:left; padding-left:10px; margin-right:10px; border-left:1px solid #fff; }
nav ul li:first-child { margin-right:0 !important; }
nav ul li a { color:#fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help you....

But i have done some works. you can resize the window it will display in multiple "lines.

here jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/XM2qU/1/

Answer (score 0):

To your curren HTML structure, you can set some CSS to achieve a replica of the provided image:

See this working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/VRvty/)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Unternehmen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Kompetenz</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Produkte</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Partner</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">News</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 12px 0;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a {
    color: #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 17px;
}
li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0 none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Preview:**

[image]

#### Some relevant links that can help you learn about what is being suggested:

[CSS display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

[CSS Lists](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)

[CSS Padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

[CSS Tutorial, Learning CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)